# Display a limited amount of product attributes through shortcode on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

I really need some help to solve this issue.

I already have a working code which displays all the product attributes in a table form through shortcode on my product page. The code is as follows:

```
function so_39394127_attributes_shortcode( $atts ) {

global $product;

if( ! is_object( $product ) || ! $product->has_attributes() ){
    return;
}

// parse the shortcode attributes
$args = shortcode_atts( array(
    'attributes' => array_keys( $product->get_attributes() ), // by default show all attributes
), $atts );

// is pass an attributes param, turn into array
if( is_string( $args['attributes'] ) ){
    $args['attributes'] = array_map( 'trim', explode( '|' , $args['attributes'] ) );
}

// start with a null string because shortcodes need to return not echo a value
$html = '';

if( ! empty( $args['attributes'] ) ) {

    foreach ( $args['attributes'] as $attribute ) {

        // get the WC-standard attribute taxonomy name
        $taxonomy = strpos( $attribute, 'pa_' ) === true ? wc_attribute_taxonomy_name( $attribute ) : $attribute;
    
        if( taxonomy_is_product_attribute( $taxonomy ) ){

            // Get the attribute label.
            $attribute_label = wc_attribute_label( $taxonomy );

            // Build the html string with the label followed by a clickable list of terms.
            // Updated for WC3.0 to use getters instead of directly accessing property.
           $html .= '<tr class=" "><th style="background-color:white;font-size:12px;font-weight:700;width:40%;line-height:1em;">' . $attribute_label . '</th><td class="tableattr2">' . get_the_term_list( $product->get_id(), $taxonomy,' ' , ', ', )  . '</td></tr>';
        }

    }

    $html = '<table style="line-height:1em;">' . $html . '</table>';

}

return $html;add_shortcode( 'display_attributes', 'so_39394127_attributes_shortcode' );
```

And then I use the following shortcode to display it on my product page - [display_attributes] as shown in picture below:

[image]

What I want to do is to limit the number of product attributes to be shown on the product page through modification of the above code either through a limit or if possible display a certain amount of product attributes and the rest attributes hidden in a collapsible format and which expands when clicked through a button on mouse as shown in picture below:

[image]

I would be grateful if someone can help me out. Thanks.

Comment: you must add the attributes you want in your case - [display_attributes attributes="attribute1|attribute2"] another approach is instead of typing them all the time if they will be the same to add em as array in your code and loop them instead of all.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that. Can you please tell me what modification I need to add to my code to add some common attributes for all.